# Local boundedness of monotone operators in general spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

A classical result states that: If $X$ is a Banach space then every multi-valued monotone operator $T:X\to 2^{X^*}$ is locally bounded on $\operatorname*{int}D(T)$ (the interior of its domain).

I wonder whether this result still holds in a general locally convex space $X$. Here $X^*$ is the topological dual of $X$ and the weakest possible boundedness, namely, the weak-star boundedness of subsets of $X^*$.

More precisely, $T:X\to 2^{X^*}$ is locally weak-star bounded on $\operatorname*{int}D(T)$ if, for every $x_0\in\operatorname*{int}D(T)$, there is $V$ a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $T(V)$ is weak-star bounded in $X^*$.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but I have found these references which do extend the result in Banach spaces to *some* locally convex spaces (Frechet spaces and locally convex Haussdorf spaces): [link 1](http://jpeypou.mat.utfsm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Gajardo_Morales_Peypouquet_JMAA.pdf), [link 2](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr029-LocBoundedness.pdf), [link 3](http://www.math.ntua.gr/~ypoly/ARTICLES%20(POLYRAKIS)/Nonlinear%20monotone%20operators....pdf). I am not sure if they use the same notion of boundedness you ask for, though.

Comment: @NateRiver The local boundedness in the sense of equicontinuity has been completely solved recently in topological vector spaces. In simple words a monotone operator is locally bounded on the algebraic interior of its domain if and only if the space is barreled. Of course the 2nd paper you mentioned is the classical result on the topic, the third is an extension of the topic, while the first paper results on local boundedness can be found in some previous papers that are cited in that paper.